# Date formatting a character variable in SAS

Tags: date, input, formatting, sas

I have a character variable with a the value like this:

```
Aug 1, 2015
```

I want to have this date value in a date9. and a DDMMYYD10. format.

This is what I have tried:

```
month=upcase(substr(startdato,1,3));
day=0!!substr(startdato,5,1);
year=substr(startdato, 8,4);
startdato_a=trim(day)!!trim(month)!!trim(year);

FORMAT  Startdato2 date9.;
format startdato3 DDMMYYD10.;

Startdato2 = INPUT(startdato_a,date9.);
Startdato3 = INPUT(startdato_a,date9.);
```

I get this output:

```
month=AUG
day=01
year=2015
startdato_a=01AUG2015
startdato2=.
startdato3=.
```

Why don't I get values in startdato2 and startdato3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting missing values due to leading / trailing whitespace in `startdato_a`, which prevents the informat from working properly. If you do `input(strip(startdato_a),date9.)` instead, it works as expected.

However, there is a much simpler way of doing this:

```
data want;
textdate = 'Aug 1, 2015';
date = input(textdate,anydtdte11.);
format date date9.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I thought that I took care of the leading and trailing blanks with the trim function. I used the much simpler way and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Output your character variables using the `$QUOTE.` function is a handy way to see leading blanks.  Doing this you can see the what is causing the trouble with the INPUT() function.

```
startdato="Aug 1, 2015"
month="AUG"
day="           01"
year="2015"
startdato_a="           01AUG2015"
```

The cause of this is including a numeric constant when generating that character string.

```
day=0!!substr(startdato,5,1);
```

SAS had to convert the 0 into a string so it used `best12.` format which is why there are 11 leading blanks in the value of DAY. You could have use a string literal instead.

```
day='0'!!substr(startdato,5,1);
```

Which would yield better results.

```
startdato="Aug 1, 2015"
month="AUG"
day="01"
year="2015"
startdato_a="01AUG2015"
Startdato2=01AUG2015
startdato3=01-08-2015
```